# Is it possible to merge column counts in pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have data as following:[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwbuh.png)

This data was deployed like this because base datafile had them combined into 1 column separated by comma. Therefore I used "Text to Columns" function what resulted in 11 different columns.

With this data I created pivot table as following:[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTPFl.png)

**The problem lies in that the Action columns have same text value from time to time and I would love to have them merged into one count column so that the pivot table would not look hideous like it is now.**

Comment: Unless you have some logic that can be programmed, or calculated by formulas, as to what should be grouped, I think you'd have to just manually group them.

Comment: You should provide a small example of your desired results.